# Как заставить препроцессор понимать Liquid в Jade?

Tags: jade, jekyll

Prepros, конечно, не понимает Liquid в Jade.
Как его заставить, чтобы понимал?
Или, вообще, как тогда вообще можно использовать Jekyll вместе с Jade?
Есть какие-то трюки, может? Я не додумываюсь.

[image: 123]

Comment: А зачем вам вообще Jade? Без подтекста, мне правда интересно.

Comment: Что значит, - зачем? :D
Тулсы учат, чтобы упрощать жизнь. С этим Джейд и Сасс (а мне такая связка милее всего) справляются на ура.

Собственно, я могу достигнуть цели (написать страницы), используя чистый Html, но есть же смысл при этом сэкономить на времени и на неувеличении межпозвоночной грыжи. Я считаю, есть.

Comment: @D-side, Хотя... я уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос на своем любимом канале на ютубе - [DevTips](https://youtu.be/nY4kQssg3lw?t=2m12s).
прошу прощения)

Comment: Окей, а с вопросом что? Запостите ответ?

Comment: @D-side, уже кинул же - ссылкой на канал на ютубе.

Comment: Ссылка не является ответом сама по себе.

Comment: @D-side, как это не является, если ответ на свой вопрос я всё же нашел именно там? :D

Comment: Потому что это ссылка, а ответ находится уже за ней. [Но это сейчас.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/181100)

Comment: @D-side, ну можно использовать gulp для решения.
Нормально? Намного яснее стало нежели чем без видео?
Кто впервые о gulp услышал, много поняли? А ведь это огромное болото.
А на видео всё прекрасно показывается.

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. Ответ полагается описывать в поле ввода ответа. Внизу. И не в формате видео. Если не будете его писать, так и скажите :)

Comment: @D-side, я не понимаю зачем и больше скажу: не знаю, что написать.
Я написал ответ в одну строчку: можно использовать галп для решения.
Но насколько это ответ, я даже не могу сказать, наверно, на 0%, хотя сразу понятно куда копать.
А ссылка видео, на которую ты нажимаешь и сразу же попадаешь на момент в нём, где Тревис сразу в блокноте пишет "Jekyll и Jade" - тулсы, которые он хочет использовать.

Я не понимаю, почему для тебя это не ответ на мой вопрос)
Если бы мне так ответили я был бы доволен сполна.

Comment: Я вам выше оставил ссылку на обстоятельное описание того, почему здесь не приветствуются ответы-ссылки. То есть, полноценный ответ вы писать не намерены. Я понял. Я пошёл дальше :) В полноценном ответе мог быть набор NodeJS-пакетов и Gulp-конфиг (или его фрагмент), который позволяет решить вышеописанную задачу. Ссылку на видео можно (а вероятно и нужно) приложить как первоисточник. Но в ответе должен быть непосредственно ответ, а не ссылка на оный.

Comment: @D-side, не-не-не, не уходи, щас будет интересное. Сначала напомню твои слова: "Потому что это ссылка, а ответ находится уже за ней. ".
Ну смотри, если я его выложу на гитхаб, то это ведь тоже будет ссылка, как же тогда быть, это не получится ответом :D
А ведь готовое решение Тревиса есть по ссылке, которое находится под видео, которое я скинул. Понимаешь? Целых 2 перехода придется сделать, чтобы найти инфу, которая, кстати, разжевывается в этом же самом видео :D
Я прусь с твоей логики XD
Вот реализация на гитхабе: [злостная_ссылка_которая_не_лечит_рак](https://vk.cc/5Yty3Q)

Comment: Это не я придумал. Прочитайте: [Ответ-ссылка не приветствуется?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1805/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F) Да, выкладывание конфига на гитхаб и приложение ссылки на него тоже не является ответом. То, что это помогло найти ответ сейчас лично вам, не гарантирует, что это поможет кому-то через год. Если решение слишком большое, объясните его суть и опишите используемые инструменты. Если не можете -- ну, не пишите :)

Comment: @D-side, Понятное дело, что до такого нельзя додуматься, можно лишь слепо следовать глупым правилам. Но тут (конкретно тут) достаточно здравого смысла, если честно. Я ответ нашел полностью на видео, ссылку на него и привел.

Comment: @VostokSisters правила созданы, чтобы не было плохих ответов. вот добавите Вы ссылку на видео и что потом? нужно будет потратить доп время, чтобы перейти по ссылке, потом убедиться, что видео или канал удален/удалено и поругать автора ответа. Если Вы поняли ответ почему Вы так упорно не хотите написать основное, чтобы другие участники столкнувшись с Вашей проблемой могли сразу получить качественный ответ ? Как показывает практика, со временем многие ссылки умирают и Ваш ответ из одной ссылки будет бесполезен для общества.

Comment: @Alex, я даже не знаю, что умрет раньше, Ютюб или этот сайт :D
Если, конечно, исключить, что автор через какое-то время удалит весь свой канал (что также маловероятно).
Завтра запишу по шагам, так и быть.

Comment: @VostokSisters все возможно, не раз уже натыкались на мертвые ссылки. От всех тех кто столкнется с Вашей проблемой, Вам большое спасибо за будущий ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кротко отвечая на свой же вопрос, скажу: можно компилировать Jade, используя Gulp, к которому также будет привешен Jekyll. Но нельзя заставить Jade понимать Liquid, который использует Jekyll, потому что сам Jekyll не компилирует Jade. Ну как нельзя... Накодить-то всё можно, но я говорю про пользовательский уровень. Таких плагинов даже для Gulp нет и вряд ли будет.

Так что, как я хотел, не получится. Можно свободно использовать Prepros, инклюдя в лейауты и сами же инклюды с помощью Liquid посредством Jekyll, на какой платформе бы вы его не использовали. Я рекомендую присмотреться к Gulp.